# Write an aphorism using valid code

Tags: popularity-contest

Can you write an [aphorism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphorism) in at most 4 lines of code ?

Code should read as much as possible as an aphorism in plain English and should return the boolean `true`.

Language: of choice.

Criteria for accepted answer: Most votes in 180 <s>30</s> days. (8<sup>th</sup> of July 2014)

Originality: can be an old aphorism but a creative one would be much more appreciated.

Comment: What is the max line length ?

Comment: @kyle k, 90 characters should should suffice, mostly for estetic, readability reasons, also good aphorisms tend to be short :)

Comment: Ruby - `!!"[ insert whatever aphorism you want here ]"`

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow That would be a valid answer but I doubt that would get much of the votes.

Comment: Not sure that Shakespeare quotes qualify as aphorisms.

Comment: @Blazemonger I think **that quote** qualifies as an aphorism

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## Python

```
import this
love = this
this is love, love is not True or False, love is love
# (True, True, True)
```

Okay, this returns a tuple of Truths, but that itself evaluates as True anyway.

Answer (score 29):

### Forth

```
2 : b or ! 2 ." b" ;
: that s" the questi" on ;
```

Answer (score 20):

## C:

You'll have to squint a bit to read this one :-)

```
int x(){ int __,L        ;
     return (__ |__ ||__ |__ ,__,__ ,__ ,__ ,__  ,
             __||  1||__ |  1L/L|__||__|1/__|  1L)
                                ;   }
```

You might notice a potential division-by-zero error on line 3, but this is never executed because the expression evaluates as `true` before the calculation is performed.

Comment: Forest gump! +1

Comment: Could you please translate, for those of us without the necessary squinting skills?

Comment: @Bob Do you want a breakdown of the C code, or a clearer rendering of the ASCII art?

Comment: Oh, the C code is easy enough (`__` is an identifier, couple bitwise and logical ORs and comma operators, which are all insignificant because it's all logical ORed with a `1` evaluating to true). It's the ASCII art that's a little difficult to read.

Comment: @Bob [OK, here's something similar.](http://pastebin.com/kjpnCU8b) (Not valid C code, but easier to read, I hope.)

Comment: Thanks! It's obvious in retrospect :\ (I was trying to read it one line at a time)

Answer (score 19):

It's difficult to avoid string literals, comments and tricks fo this kind, but I tried to keep them to a mininum. Also, the first line makes no sense. Well, I had `fun` doing it

### F#

```
(fun () -> (fun (_) -> // fun fun? wtf
try not <| failwith("me") ; (*but*) with |Failure((*co*)me(*s*)) -> true)("learning"))()
// "Try not to fail with me, but with failure comes true learning
```

I could also do some declaration abusing, but I ended up not finding a way to return true:

```
let the,bodies,hit_the=floor(0.0),(),()
```

or

```
let the_games=bigint() //pun intended
```

I really need to stop with the puns.

Answer (score 18):

## C

No string literals or comments:

```
Better(to,re);main(silent){and();}be(thought,a,fool){}
than(to,open,your,mouth);and(){}remove(all,doubt);
```

Split over two lines, but one would work fine as well.

When compiled using gcc on Linux (x86-64), this produces an executable which exits with success (exit code 0), the same as the `true` Unix utility; this being how I choose to interpret the requirement of returning boolean `true` in a non-scripting language.

Note: notwithstanding the abuse of the "implicit int" rule, the principal trick behind this program is that while a C program that falls off the end of `main` without a `return` statement will usually result in a non zero exit code, by calling another function we can set the `EAX` register which is then used as the exit code of the program. This is of course totally undefined behaviour and utterly non portable.

Answer (score 17):

## Python

```
war=peace=freedom=slavery=ignorance=strength=0
war is peace|freedom is slavery|ignorance is strength

Power=a=means=it=an=end=0
Power is not (a, means, it is (an, end))
```

## JavaScript

```
You=true;function BigBrother(){};BigBrother.isWatching=function(y){return y};
BigBrother.isWatching(You)
```

Answer (score 15):

## C#:

```
short life = 0;
return (life is short);
```

"Life is short" (Hippocrates)

Comment: Too bad there is no literal specifiers for shorts!  It would be neat to do `var life = 0s;`

Answer (score 14):

## Ruby

```
class String
  def before(b) self < b end
end
```

A bit lengthy, but gets us a few aphorisms:

```
"age".before("beauty")
"business".before("pleasure")
"pearls".before("swine")
```

And (stretching slightly):

```
dont = []; y = 1
dont.count + y or ('chickens'.before('they hatch'))
```

Answer (score 11):

## Scala

```
Some apply Double forall _; None isEmpty
```

Answer (score 11):

## CoffeeScript

```
2 * @wrong isnt @right
```

=> true

Answer (score 10):

## C++

```
bool life = true;
bool fair = false;

assert(life != fair);
```

Answer (score 8):

## Python

```
love=[True];all,fair,war=love*3
all is fair in love and war
```

Answer (score 7):

An aphorism about http verbs, in

### Ruby

```
puts do
something idempotent but are considered to be unsafe
because if the value at the beginning of a chain of calls is one possibly the value at the
end != 1
```

Answer (score 4):

### C

```
if ((ifs && ands) == (pots && pans))
    work_for_tinkers_hands = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript

```
function be(who) {
   if (who == 'thine own self') {
      return true;
   }
}
```

An approximation of "To thine own self be true."

I'm kind of fudging with the requirements, since it only returns true in one particular case ... but I'm hoping you'll let it slide because the return value is actually part of the aphorism.

Answer (score 4):

I got a wonderful error while attempting this:

It's very much inspired by Darren Stone's answer.

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'tis nobler' in mind to suffer the The Slings and Arrows of outrageous fortune

## Javascript

```
[2].be || ! [2].be ; this.is, "the question"
```

It returns an implicit true.

Slightly less terse, with a question mark:

```
[2].be || ! [2].be? is = this: !"the question"
```

Answer (score 4):

## C

```
main(int I,char **think) {char *a="there"; for (;--I;) a['m'];}
```

Comment: You can remove the types in declarations. Also something has to be done to a's declaration... It gets in the way when you read

Comment: I left them because my compiler gave me errors without them, so I wanted to be very adherent :P

Answer (score 4):

## C

```
int main(int fear, int* computers){ int

    i; do { !fear; computers[i]; fear; "the lack of them";

} while();return true;}
```

*I do not fear computers, I fear the lack of them.*

-Isaac Asimov

Answer (score 3):

A bit lazy, but my take.

## Python:

```
life = short = True; art = long = True; life=art
life is short and art is long
```

## JavaScript:

```
The = word = 'Yoga'
has = been = 'vulgarized'
and = does = not=  mean = anything =Date.now() ,!''
//Swami Rama
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP

```
$all = array('not well', 'not well', 'not well', 'well'); 
$end = array_pop($all);
$all = ($end == 'well') ? $end : 'not well';
return true;
```

"All's well that ends well."

Answer (score 3):

## Q

`` any bird:`int$"hehand"=2^`int$"hebush" ``

and

`(./) 2_iscomp:any 3,'s:"a",'"crowd"`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP

An apple a day...

```
$aphorism = function(){
    for($day=1;$day<=365;$day++) $apple++;
    return ($apple==365) ? true : 'doctor';
};
```

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp

```
(Do ((as)) ('(I say no)t) as I do)
(time (and 'tide (wait-for 'no-man))) ;requires sbcl
```

Answer (score 3):

## Lua

```
-- all search is in vain
function search() end
-- only the void is true
function void() return function() return true end, true end
-- and what remains is to
for ever in void() do repeat search("light") until true end
return true
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript

```
return (Do || !Do) || (there == !try);
```

```
return 2 * be || !(2 * be);
```

Comment: Upvote for the Yoda one, but I am thinking there should be a ban on "To be or not to be".

Answer (score 3):

### R

```
the_whole <- c(-1,-1)
the_part <- -1
the_whole > sum(the_part,the_part)
```

-Socrates

Answer (score 2):

### [Simply-Basic 84](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1274)

```
Label 1;a random number between 0 and 1~should be stored in~A
If A is equal to 1 Then Display A End;Stop&Else,Go to label 1
:End; Otherwise destroy quantum transmitters internationally.
Since quantum transmitters are gone, power lost. KA-POW, yes?
```

Answer (score 2):

## Prolog

```
waste(not).

want(X) :-
    waste(X).
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python**

```
be = that = the = question = 1
2 - be or not 2 - be
that is the & question
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby**

Not the most elegant solution, but very easy to read

```
def you_know_meaning(x) true end

!!!("aphorism" != "aphorism" unless you_know_meaning "aphorism")

=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

## JAVA

```
public static boolean think(){return true;}public static boolean so()
{return true;}public static boolean be(){return true;}static{boolean i=true;
    System.out.println((i==think())?so():i==be());
}
```

I think so i be --Descartes

Answer (score 2):

## C++

```
int main() {
  int right,might;
  might==right;
}
```

Might is right.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell

Be original!

```
do otherwise
```

It returns True.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol

```
Rebol []
between: :if thought: expression: true lies: func ['a 'b] [a != b]

between thought and expression [lies a lifetime]
```

#### Some explanation

The above code translates to:

```
if thought and expression [lies word-arg1 word-arg2]
```

The `if` statement is true so the `lies` function is called which returns *true* as along as the two arguments provided are different.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl

```
sub between (&@) { $_[1] if $_[0]->() } sub lies { $_[0] ne $_[1] }
my ($thought, $expression) = (1,1);

between {$thought and $expression} lies a => 'lifetime';
```

NB. Above works fine with (or without) `strict` and `warnings` pragmas.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby vs Friedrich Nietzsche

```
=> class Lie
=>   def self.is_a_condition_of?(life);true;end
=> end
=> Lie.is_a_condition_of?("life") # => true
```

Comment: You're admitting also that self is a condition of life :) +1

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript

`get: with(this) 1;`

I think this makes sense.

Edit: was notified it didn't return `true`, well now it does.

Comment: Doesn't return true

Answer (score 1):

Is my use of the literal string true cheating?

This is an AutoHotkey script:

```
Be("true") to yourself

Be(msg) {
    MsgBox % msg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol

```
love: true 
war:  false

if true? any [love is blind and war is hell] [make love not war]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not one of my favourite songs, still a great album.

## PHP

```
$_GET['this'] or die(!0);
```

**Reads as:** Get this or die! (No!)

*Get This*
Slipknot
1999

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL

I made several attempts at this challenge before arriving at an answer that expresses truth through the code itself. After a few attempts at turning favorite quotes into pithy code translations, I realized the way to go was to set aside quotation entirely and let the language of choice simply speak the wisdom it is capable of speaking.

Since SQL is verbose, I have chosen to break this 4-line program into more lines for ease of reading without horizontal scrolling. The properly "golfed" version may be found on [this SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8)

```
DECLARE @mindInTurmoil BIT = 'True'
Samsara: SELECT 'equanimity' AS Attitude, 0 AS Ego INTO #Self
    WHERE @mindInTurmoil = 'True' 
IF (SELECT TOP 1 Attitude FROM #Self ORDER BY Ego) = 'equanimity' 
    SET @mindInTurmoil = 'False' ELSE GOTO Samsara
SELECT CASE @mindInTurmoil 
    WHEN 'True' THEN 'False' WHEN 'False' THEN 'True' END AS Liberation
```

Returns:

```
Liberation
----------
True
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java (probably others too)

```
boolean hasExceptions(Rule rule) { return rule != this; }
```

"There are always exceptions, except to this rule." - by me.

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript**

```javascript
function healthy_community(diversity){
    return (diversity === true) ? true : false;
}
healthy_community(true);
```

Comment: why not just `return diversity` ?

Comment: well if you pass 'kinda sorta' it will return false. it must be absolutely true in type and value.

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy

```
short Short;
short life = Short;
assert life.is(Short);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java**

```
for (Person person : people) {
    if (!HouseTypeEnum.GLASS_HOUSE.equals(person.getResidence().getHouseType()))
        throw new StonesException();
}
```

Comment: Two problems: This doesn't compile because we don't have a `Person` class or a `HouseTypeEnum` or a `StonesException` or (etc). Also "should return the boolean true." This code doesn't return any value.

Answer (score 1):

**Mathematica**

```
 mo[thing__] := MemberQ[{thing}, money | problems | True]
 mo[money~mo~problems]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript

```
with = javascript = we = can = create = any = aphorism = returning = true;
```

Comment: Yes, but is it creative? ;)

Answer (score 1):

### C

This quote is a line from My Fair Lady. See here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVmU3iANbgk

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*the rain */int /*Spain falls*/ main/*ly*/(){return puts("on the plane")>0?1:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

### TI-BASIC

```
2_be or not(2_be)
```